# Heroku couldn't retrieve data from db (gives 503 (Service Unavailable)) after deployment MERN app

Tags: node.js, reactjs, mongodb, heroku, mern

My MERN stack app works fine locally but after a successful deployment on Heroku, the app is working but couldn't retrieve the data from Mongodb. items didn't show up, user cant login and on the console it gives this error:

```
https://tranquil-ridge-25766.herokuapp.com/api/items 503 (Service Unavailable)
```

I tried many stuff but no help. I suspect i did something wrong on the

> if (process.env.NODE_ENV === "production")....

line. (I also add NODE.ENV = production in the Config Vars in Heroku Settings)

Here is my server.js :

```
const express = require("express");
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
const bodyParser = require("body-parser");
const config = require("config");
const cors = require("cors");
const path = require("path");

const app = express();
app.use(cors());
//Bodyparser Middleware
app.use(bodyParser.json());

// DB config

const db = config.get("mongoURI");

//connect to Mongo
mongoose
  .connect(db, {
    useNewUrlParser: true,
    useCreateIndex: true,
    useUnifiedTopology: true
  })
  .then(() => console.log("MongoDB Connected..."))
  .catch(err => console.log(err));

//Use routes

app.use("/api/items", require("./routes/api/items"));
app.use("/api/users", require("./routes/api/users"));

//Serve static assets if in production
if (process.env.NODE_ENV === "production") {
  //set static folder
  app.use(express.static("client/build"));

  app.get("*", (req, res) => {
    res.sendFile(path.resolve(__dirname, "client", "build", "index.html"));
  });
}

const port = process.env.PORT || 5000;

app.listen(port, () => console.log(`Server started on port ${port}`));
```

Comment: Is it using the following format?, mongodb://myDBReader:D1fficultP%40ssw0rd@mongodb0.example.com:27017/admin

Comment: You meaan Mongo URI? this is it: `mongodb+srv://name:password@mernshopping-nixua.mongodb.net/test?retryWrites=true&w=majority`

Comment: yes that looks good.  I'm wondering if you are still connecting to your localhost,, i have to post some code.

Comment: Yep localhost is working well. Just it seems it couldn't connect the database after Heroku  deploy

Comment: Check the answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe we can pull some information that will tell us exactly what db we are getting.

```
   const dbCheck = mongoose
      .connect(db, {
        useNewUrlParser: true,
        useCreateIndex: true,
        useUnifiedTopology: true
      })
      .then(() => console.log(dbCheck, '---db check----))
      .catch(err => console.log(err));
```

This may give us some more information on what database you are connected to, also it's hard to tell but how are you checking to see if you are using the prod db?  Are you using something like this?

```
mongoose.connect(process.env.MONGODB_URI ||
    'mongodb://localhost:27017/kb')
```

If you are pumping in the NODE_ENV in your json, are you sure it's exactly "production"?  You could run a

```
if (process.env.NODE_ENV == "production") {
```

This way you can might find that there is an extra space in your NODE_ENV or something like that, just for troubleshooting purposes.

Comment: I added the dbCheck stuff nothing happened, still the same, it works on local, can not fetch data in heroku, and nothing in console... And I dont get the second code, my only mongoose.connect is that one in the server.js

Comment: If you are using heroku you should just push the mongoDB as a config var in the settings page on your app.  Bring that in, check for that, if not local host.  Also, if you have windows you can download mongo commmunity, and check to see if your data base is actually up

Answer (score 2):

Ok, at last, I find my solution. For anyone having the same type of troubles, you should follow these 4 steps to deploy a MERN stack on Heroku:

1- `const port = process.env.PORT || 5000;` make sure you add an env variable for port in server.js

2- also add process.env.MONGODB_URI variable to your mongoose.connect

```
mongoose
  .connect(process.env.MONGODB_URI || db, {
    useNewUrlParser: true,
    useCreateIndex: true,
    useUnifiedTopology: true
  })
  .then(() => console.log("MongoDB Connected..."))
  .catch(err => console.log(err));
```

3- Add an if statement to set a static folder in production. It should be after your app routes

```
if (process.env.NODE_ENV === "production") {
  app.use(express.static("client/build"));

  app.get("*", (req, res) => {
    res.sendFile(path.resolve(__dirname, "client", "build", "index.html"));
  });
}
```

4- Add these line to main folders package.json file in the `scripts` object

`"heroku-postbuild": "cd client && npm install && npm run build"`

after these steps just create by "heroku login" and "heroku create " on the terminal, final step is adding mongoLab addon to heroku:

```
heroku addons:create mongolab:sandbox
```

You need to verify a credit card to Heroku to work this out but don't worry, "sandbox" is a free option and it never charges money. So your app is ready, for detailed explanation and furthermore, Thanks to this awesome guy, check it out on his youtube channel: [Deploy a MERN Stack App to Heroku](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=e1LaekAnVIM)